# Need help while installing virtual box{i am a newbee} This is what I've got as errors list

Tags: command-line, 20.04, package-management, virtualbox

```
virtualbox-7.0 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.1) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5dbus5 (>= 5.14.1) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.14.1) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed or
                           libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.14.1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5help5 (>= 5.15.1) but 5.12.8-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.15.1) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 12) but 10.5.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 is to be installed
                  Depends: libvpx7 (>= 1.10.0) but it is not installable

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: There is no package named `virtualbox-7.0` in the Ubuntu repositories. This suggests that you are following random internet instructions that have led you astray. Your error message simply means that your `virtualbox-7.0` package, wherever you got it from, is not compatible with your Ubuntu system.

Comment: There are simpler ways to install Virtualbox. If you purge all your changes and restore a stock Ubuntu system, a simple `sudo apt install virtualbox` will install the slightly-older-but-tested-and-working version of Virtualbox from the Ubuntu repositories.